# Permit URL paths with cutom AuthorizationManager in Spring Boot 3.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have the following Security configuration running with Spring Boot 3.0.6:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {

  private final JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver authenticationManagerResolver;
  private final OpaAuthorizationManager opaAuthorizationManager;

  @Autowired
  public SecurityConfig(@Value("${com.example.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer}") String[] issuer,
                        OpaAuthorizationManager opaAuthorizationManager) {
    this.authenticationManagerResolver = new JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver(issuer);
    this.opaAuthorizationManager = opaAuthorizationManager;
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/health")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/openapi/openapi.yml")).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().access(this.opaAuthorizationManager))
        .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver));
    return http.build();
  }
}
```

For the restricted path everything works fine.

But for the paths that I have configured to be permitted, I get an HTTP 401 status code. My custom `AuthorizationManager` gets not called for the permitted paths (what I expect). Instead, when debugging I see that the `DefaultBearerTokenResolver` throws a `OAuth2AuthenticationException`. This results in a try to render the `/error` path, which is not permitted from the `AuthorizationManager`. Hence; a HTTP 401 is returned.

How do I configure Spring Security in this case to be able to call the permitted paths without a JWT and without authorization?

Comment: Have you tried to create a `WebSecurityCustomizer` an ignore those paths yet ?

Answer (score 0):

I use requestMatchers like this:

```
.requestMatchers("/enable").permitAll()
```